# what is the version of Android SDK Platform-tools and Android SDK Tools required to build maximo anaywhere 7.6.3.1 apps?

Tags: android, sdk, ibm-mobilefirst, maximo, maximo-anywhere

what is the version of Android SDK Platform-tools and Android SDK Tools required to build maximo anaywhere 7.6.3.1 apps?

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working? How about API Level 26 or above? Does those work?

Comment: @VivinK If I installed API 26 the  Android SDK Platform-tools and Android SDK Tools will installed automatically or I must install them manually. in case of manually what is the correct versions I must install

Comment: Install API Level 26 and update the SDK tools and platform-tools if required.

Comment: @VivinK to wich version should I update

Comment: Take the version 26 or above. You really need to try things out first.

Answer (score 0):

Platform-tools and Android SDK Tools Version required to build Maximo anywhere 7.6.3.1 is Andoird-23.
Install the version and update the build properties.